# Request URI returns HTTP 401

Tags: python, django, api, rest, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn api along with Python, Django and Linux. The problem I face is when I apply filters to the request uri.

Supposingly `/v1/posts/{post_id}:(id,type,category,creator,title,summary,creation-timestamp,likes,comments,attachment,site-group-post-url)` returns a xml for the data of the following post. But if I apply some filter to it i.e

`/v1/posts/{post_id}:(id,type,category,creator,title,summary,creation-timestamp,likes,comments,attachment,site-group-post-url)?count=5&start=5` this would return a HTTP 401 UNAUTHORIZED

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could your OAuth library be incorrectly calculating the request signature?

Confirm that it matches the one generated by this page:

https://developer.linkedin.com/oauth-test-console

Comment: Hey Adam, I am using httplib in python. Below is the piece of code which I use. It works perfectly, meaning that oauth is alright as well as the headers and signature's. I don't understand how can I request with certain filters e.g count=5&start=5
....................................................CODE STARTS->
# make the HTTP request
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection(API_ENDPOINT)
connection.request("GET", "/v1/groups/xyz/posts", body = None, headers = {'Authorization': header})

response = connection.getresponse()
response = response.read()
connection.close()